# Issue on Jquery Background Image Fade In and Out

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to change a background image of a html5 canvas from dropdown select by using following code

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    if (this.value ==1){
      $('#canvas').css('background-image').fadeOut();
      $('#canvas').css({'background': 'url(http://localhost/MapBox/img/cal_NAs.png) no-repeat top right, url(http://localhost/MapBox/img/bg_sh.png) no-repeat top right','background-color' : 'grey'}).fadeIn();
    }
})
```

but this is not doing the job and I am getting this error on console : Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. 
can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because

```
$('#canvas').css('background-image')
```

returns the value of the 'background-image' CSS property of the element, which is a string. Strings don't have a method called `fadeOut` so when you try to call `fadeOut()` it fails.

However, you have a more fundamental issue - `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` apply to elements, not styles of elements.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002351/jquery-fade-css-background-image-change) for examples of fading backgrounds

Comment: Thanks CupawnTae, sao what is the solution how can I replace background images with using jquery effects?

Comment: @Behseini I added a link to a related question that should help

Answer (score 0):

Fading background images is not a trivial thing.

You should probably look into a solution like this: [Change the body background image with fade effect in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255903/change-the-body-background-image-with-fade-effect-in-jquery)