# How to apply JQuery fade functionality to between changing the background Images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fadein, fadeout

I want to add jquery `fade()` functionality so that images changes with fade. 
The problem is I want these images in sequence, not randomly.

```js
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function () {
    var backgroundImg=["https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRyB57zuc4bms-hDtWMa-4BZvscIlJDm4r7a9WLaO4SAxUvKM-DDA",
                    "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQBinSpWOvAtkxjmkf709O3rjH2ObRbWAEn9s0JcWaeL6LMtCbOrQ",
                    "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRKY4J2qIFqkuDnABMzeypywbMSZL1cleS8vpySz0KD02wOYORU1g",
                    "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRQkdQT0zN0xDVP-VuvwojSbS5dOstX14eZvJCOWNPxKJ5dWTIc"
    ]
    setInterval(changeImage, 1000);
    var i = 0;
    function changeImage() {   
      document.getElementById('slide').style.backgroundImage = "url('"+backgroundImg[i]+"')";
      i++; 
      if(i == 4){
        i = 0;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="slide" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the body background image with fade effect in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255903/change-the-body-background-image-with-fade-effect-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Remove  `var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3));` and add `var i = 0;` outside the function, then inside the function increment the `i` value until it reaches 4, then get it back to 0.
like this :

```
setInterval(changeImage, 1000);
var i = 0;
function changeImage() {   
   document.getElementById('slide').style.backgroundImage = "url('"+backgroundImg[i]+"')";
   i++; if (i == 4){i = 0;}
}
```

Comment: Rasheed Sir Yes its working, thank you so much, also what about fade(); functionality ?

Comment: you can use the same code but with a small change from `document.getElementById('slide').style.backgroundImage = "url('"+backgroundImg[i]+"')";` to `$('#slide').fadeIn(500).css("background-image", "url('"+backgroundImg[i]+"')").fadeOut(500);`

Comment: and of course you can tweak it a little to your preference.

Comment: Nice answer, but let's tweak it. Instead of i++; if (i == 4){i = 0;} use (i = ((i + 1) % 4));

Answer (score 0):

JQuery can only fade Html-Elements. So you need add the images as html-tag ()

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var backgroundImg=[ "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRyB57zuc4bms-hDtWMa-4BZvscIlJDm4r7a9WLaO4SAxUvKM-DDA",
                            "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQBinSpWOvAtkxjmkf709O3rjH2ObRbWAEn9s0JcWaeL6LMtCbOrQ",
                            "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRKY4J2qIFqkuDnABMzeypywbMSZL1cleS8vpySz0KD02wOYORU1g",
                            "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRQkdQT0zN0xDVP-VuvwojSbS5dOstX14eZvJCOWNPxKJ5dWTIc"];
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="slide" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"></div>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(let i=0; i<backgroundImg.length; i++){
        $("#slide").append("<img src='"+backgroundImg[i]+"' alt='pic_"+i+"' style='position: absolute; display:none;' />");
    }
    $("#slide img:nth-child(1)").show();

    let pic = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        next = pic+1;
        if(pic == backgroundImg.length-1){
            next = 0;
        } else if(pic == backgroundImg.length) {
            pic = 0;
            next = 1;
        }
        $("#slide img:nth-child("+(pic+1)+")").fadeOut();
        $("#slide img:nth-child("+(next+1)+")").fadeIn();
        pic++;
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
</html>
```

I'm sure, someone could do this better but it works.